# Is $W_G(S) = \{ g\in G \mid \exists s\in S, \ gsg^{-1}\in S \} $ well-known and studied?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

Given a group $G$ and a subset of the group $S$, the normalizer $N_G(S)$ is defined as the set
$$
N_G(S) = \{ g\in G \mid \forall s\in S, \ gsg^{-1}\in S \}
$$

Is a weaker version of that (which is certainly not a group), such that
$$
W_G(S) = \{ g\in G \mid \exists s\in S, \ gsg^{-1}\in S \}
$$
well-known and studied?

Comment: What do you mean by "is there... ?", do you mean it in a "was that ever studied?" way perhaps?

Comment: Yes. Is this concept well understood, does it have nice properties, interesting applications, etc. Basically I just want an answer of the type, "yes, this is called the ____ , see source ____".

Comment: Clarified accordingly

Comment: If $e\in S$, then $W_G(S)=G$.

Comment: Extending the comment of @Shaun : if $S \cap Z(G) \neq \emptyset$, then $W_G(S)=G$.

Comment: To generalize the observation even more, if $S$ contains a conjugacy class, then $W_G(S)=G$. this includes the case of $S$ containing a central element, since central elements are their own conjugacy class.